# GET request parameters with koa-router

Tags: node.js, parameters, get, koa, koa-router

http://localhost:3000/endpoint?id=83 results in 404 (Not Found). All other routes work as expected. Am I missing something here?

```
router
  .get('/', function *(next) {
    yield this.render('index.ejs', {
      title: 'title set on the server'
    });
  })
  .get('/endpoint:id', function *(next) {
    console.log('/endpoint:id');
    console.log(this.params);
    this.body = 'Endpoint return';
  })
```

koa-router documentation on parameters

```
//Named route parameters are captured and added to ctx.params.

router.get('/:category/:title', function *(next) {
  console.log(this.params);
  // => { category: 'programming', title: 'how-to-node' }
});
```

Request in angular controller:

```
 $http.get('/endpoint', {params: { id: 223 }})
    .then(
      function(response){
        var respnse = response.data;
        console.log(response);
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 10):

Your parameter format is not right

Replace your route with this

```
.get('/endpoint/:id', function *(next) {
    console.log(this.params);
    this.body = 'Endpoint return';
  })
```

### Request#query

```
.get('/endpoint/', function *(next) {
    console.log(this.query);
    this.body = 'Endpoint return';
  })
```

### Request#param

```
.get('/endpoint/:id', function *(next) {
    console.log(this.params);
    this.body = 'Endpoint return';
  })
```

Comment: Dosen't work Im afraid. Adding both routes (Request#query & Request#param) just serve the "query"-one regardless if I have parameters in the request.
Defining only  " .get('/endpoint/:id', funtion... " returns 404

Comment: Can you post your code from where you are requesting?

Comment: Added the angular $http request in the question. Also just using the browser url to test

Comment: mean you are doing get('/arrow/:id', function *(next) {}?

Comment: Do like this get('/endpoint', function *(next) {
and check console.log(this.params || this.request.params)

Comment: The '/arrow/:id' was wrong. I tried both '/endpoint:id', '/endpoint/:id', both 404. '/endpoint' does not hold any parameters

Comment: mean `/endpoint` is right route, you should check params by this.request.query or this.request.params.

Comment: I think generator functions are for an older version of Koa, Koa 2 uses async callbacks

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it is too late, but for the ones who have this problem yet, it is not with the keyword this, but ctx. The following, when consulted with the url

http://myweb.com/endpoint/45

```
 .get('/endpoint/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
     console.log(ctx.params);
     this.body = 'Endpoint return';   })
```

returns the following json:

```
{ "id": "45"}
```

And this:

```
 .get('/endpoint/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
     console.log(ctx.params.id);
     this.body = 'Endpoint return';   })
```

when consulted with the same url returns

```
45
```

Edit: The good news is that the two endpoints are really different. You can have the both endpoints and the router can decide between the two based on the url you type in your browser.